# Firefox plays audio on wrong output device

Tags: firefox, audio, hdmi

I have my video and audio connected through an HDMI cable to my screen. I have GF108 selected as the default audio output device and all audio goes there except Firefox. Firefox instead insists on sending audio to the onboard audio hardware. This happened a couple of days ago when the computer started on the wrong video port.

Comment: If you change the default audio device to the onboard audio, restart, then back to GF108, does Firefox get it right?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently not, but I finally made it work by removing the onboard device completely from the list in Linux Pulse controller.

Comment: Sadly, that's not a solution for me. I'm having this issue too, where Firefox always plays out of one specific audio device (not my system default or the one I have active) even if I restart Firefox or the machine. Chrome/Brave respect my chosen audio device so I am forced to use it for listening to music and YouTube.